# Left off four publications and counting by old PI? What to do?

Tags: publications, assistant-professor

I had worked in a research position before moving to my current job.  While working there I synthesised numerous compounds and developed the methodologies to do so, I sent these off to a number of collaborators in large quantities.

I have now found out that around four papers have been published using the materials that I prepared and sent off enabling the work.  However, on all publications.. in which my old PI is on.. it states in acknowledgements synthesised by her.. She never set foot in the lab never mind having the ability to make or synthesise them! I also still get regular messages from 'her' staff asking me for help on how to do work in which she has laid out the claim she is the world expert... they cant prepare the compounds since I have left.

Its getting a bit sickening now seeing this happening multiple times and being completely cut off and complete credit stolen, not even an acknowledgement.

Is there any thing I can do?

Many Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that the authors don't actually know who developed the materials and are just making an assumption based on the lab it came out of? When you sent it off, were you clear that it was _your_ work, rather than _our_ word? In your field is it natural to attribute everything to the PI? Any of those could point to an innocent, if unfortunate, state of affairs.

Comment: I don't know the conventions of your field, so the following suggestion might be absurd, but it seems to me that you could offer to provide the help that her staff needs but only under the condition that you be a co-author of any resulting papers. (I have no suggestion for what to do about previous papers.)

Comment: I would be replying to those requests to contact her... then see if anything happens.